# How to create text box with button in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

Using below code I am able to create button using jqgrid.

```
formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    return "<button class=\"resend\">Resend</button>";
}
```

Now I want to create textbox with button in a one column.

How can achieve to create a text box with button using the above code?

Comment: It's unclear what you try to implement. You write about creating "text box with button". What is your goal? What input data have the grid? Do you want to *fill* the `<input>` elements with some data returned from the server? Do you want that the *user are able to modify the data*? The goal of `formatter` - displaying the data, not editing. jqGrid have 3 editing modes. For example inline editing can be used to edit the data. Do you want that *custom editing control* (with both `<input type="text">` and the `<button>`) will be created *during editing* the data?

Comment: I need textbox along with button. Put data in text box and on click of button need to get text box data.

Comment: You comment gives almost no additional information. The requirements could be interpreted in many different ways. You should answer on my questions if you want that I help you. You should describe, what you need, **more detailed** on an example with test data.